# Table Subheading in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table in HTML. And it is supposed to look like:
[image: How it suppose to look like picture link]

However, I'm unable to do it.

This is my code so far...

```html
<table align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th colspan="3">Types</th>
      <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
      <td>Ok</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next to `colspan` attribute you have figured out yourself, use `rowspan` (which does basically the same, but vertically). Also, either skip `<thead>` or add an extra row for the `| A | B | C |` part. My example skips the `<thead>` as it is an easier approach.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td:empty:after {
  content: "\00a0"; /* HTML entity of &nbsp; */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">No</th>
    <th colspan="3">Types</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Remark</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of your table add `<table align="center" border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` and defining the `colspan` and `rowspan`in the table header by using following code

```
            <tr>
                <th rowspan=2>No.</th>
                <th colspan="3">Types</th>
                <th rowspan=2>Remark</th>
            </tr>
```

**Final code of your desired output**

```
<table align="center" border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan=2>No.</th>
                <th colspan="3">Types</th>
                <th rowspan=2>Remark</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Data1</td>
                <td>Data2</td>
                <td>Data3</td>
                <td>Ok</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">No</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">Types</td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">Remark</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">A</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">B</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```